how to implement ackermann_steering_controller with 4 drive joints and 2 steer joints?
I am trying to use ackermann_steering_controller for my four wheeled mobile base.I i can steer using <front_wheels_names[i]>/position using my steer joints and <rear_wheels_names[i]>/velocity using rear drive joint. but i couldn't move my front drive joints and also how to limit steer angles?

This is just not yet supported by the ackermann_steering_controller.
I wrote a summary about the equations here but this hasn't been implemented in the library yet.
Contributions are welcome!

https://control.ros.org/rolling/doc/ros2_controllers/ackermann_steering_controller/doc/userdoc.html#ackermann-steering-controller-userdoc

I wrote a summary about the equations here but this hasn't been implemented in the library yet.

Please add any additional info to the answer and not in the comments. Thanks.
